# pygsheets.Worksheet.update_cells() возвращает ошибку "Invalid value at 'data.values'

Tags: python, pygsheets

```
Код:


import pygsheets

sheet = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='service_creds.json',no_cache=True)

sh = sheet.open('my-sheet')
print(sh.id)
wks = sh.sheet1
wks.update_cell('A2', "!!!Help")
wks.update_cells('A2', "HELP")
sh.share("ХХХХХХХХХ@gmail.com")
```

И как это далее исправить ?

> `Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\beast\Desktop\lllkkk.py", line 9, in <module>
>       wks.update_cells('A2', "HELP")   File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\worksheet.py",
>   line 431, in update_cells
>       self.client.sh_update_range(self.spreadsheet.id, body, self.spreadsheet.batch_mode, parse=parse)   File
>   "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py",
>   line 352, in sh_update_range
>       self._execute_request(spreadsheet_id, final_request, batch)   File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py",
>   line 418, in _execute_request
>       response = request.execute()   File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py",
>   line 133, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py",
>   line 844, in execute
>       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
>   https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1eptzus7Xl-pF0blTrxSPQ-DH_VlQARSJwILgu0oFpYU/values/Sheet1%21A2%3AB6?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json
>   returned "Invalid value at 'data.values'
>   (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "HELP"">`

Comment: указывает вам на ошибку `line 9, in <module>
      wks.update_cells('A2', "HELP")   File` попробуйте изменить `wks.update_cells('A2', "HELP")` на `wks.update_cell('A2', "HELP")`

Comment: `wks.update_cells(...)` ожидает список или кортеж (`tuple`) в качестве второго параметра...

Comment: Благодарю
Работает

Answer (score 1):

[`pygsheets.Worksheet.update_cells(crange=None, values=None, cell_list=None, extend=False, majordim='ROWS', parse=True)`](http://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worksheet.html) ожидает в качестве `values` - список (это также может быть матрица в виде списка списков):

> **values** – matrix of values if range given, if a value is None its
>   unchanged